# "incompatible datatypes in combination" error with query on date value

Tags: java, swing, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

The intent of my overall program is to fetch values from Access database and display in jtable for a particular date.
I have a table in access database where for_date field is stored as a **Date/Time** field and format is **Short date(dd-MM-yyyy)**. Now my program requires me to retrieve the rows from the database for a particular date.I used SimpleDateFormat to convert it in the format as access database but it gives error. The error I get is:- **net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException:UCAExc:::3.0.4 incompatible datatypes in combination.This exception may happen if you add integers representing units of time directly to datetime values using the arithmetic plus operator but without specifying the unit of date.In this specific case you have to use,for example, +1 DAY**

My code is as follows:-

```
 String table_sel = "ISGS_table";
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 String date1 = sdf.format(report_date.getDate());
try{
String sql = "Select reporting_date as REPORTING_DATE,for_date as FOR_DATE,outage_date as OUTAGE_DATE,outage_time as OUTAGE_TIME,stat_detail as STATION_DETAILS,res_date as RESTORATION_DATE,rest_time as RESTORATION_TIME,rest_reason as RESTORATION_REASON from " + table_sel+" where for_date='" + date1 + "'";
Connection con = null;
            Statement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            PreparedStatement pst = null;
            String dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\Dell_PC\\Documents\\SYSTEM_OUTAGE_REPORT.accdb";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
            st = con.createStatement();
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
  con.close();   
       } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
```

Comment: Version 3.0.4 is quite old; you may want to consider upgrading to the latest version (currently 4.0.2).

Comment: I installed the 4.0.2 version now as suggested by you !

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving that error message because you are passing the value for `for_date` as a string literal. UCanAccess follows the Access SQL convention of using hash marks (`#`) as the delimiter for date/time literals.

So, this will fail with the error you cited

```sql
... WHERE for_date = '2017-02-03'
```

whereas this will work

```sql
... WHERE for_date = #2017-02-03#
```

Note that it would be considered better form if you were to use a `PreparedStatement` with

```sql
... WHERE for_date = ?
```

and pass the date value using `PreparedStatement#setDate`.

Comment: Hi Gord ! I tried what you suggested but it didn't work. I modified the sql query to sql = "Select reporting_date as REPORTING_DATE,for_date as FOR_DATE,outage_date as OUTAGE_DATE,outage_time as OUTAGE_TIME,stat_detail as STATION_DETAILS,res_date as RESTORATION_DATE,rest_time as RESTORATION_TIME,rest_reason as RESTORATION_REASON from " + table_sel+" where for_date=#2017-05-01#";  but still there was no output even though there existed a date field with value 01-05-2017 stored in my Access Database.

Comment: I also tried with preparedStatement but of no avail. sql = "Select reporting_date as REPORTING_DATE,for_date as FOR_DATE,outage_date as OUTAGE_DATE,outage_time as OUTAGE_TIME,stat_detail as STATION_DETAILS,res_date as RESTORATION_DATE,rest_time as RESTORATION_TIME,rest_reason as RESTORATION_REASON from " + table_sel+" where for_date=?";  java.util.Date utilStartDate;
            java.sql.Date sqlStartDate;
            utilStartDate = report_date.getDate();
                sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(utilStartDate.getTime()); pst.setDate(1, sqlStartDate);

Comment: See if you get a result when you use `SELECT TOP 1 ... WHERE for_date>=?` and if so, inspect the actual value of `for_date` that is returned. (Specifically, see if it has a time component associated with it.)

Comment: not working @Gord! It just doesn't seem to match the date value. What should I do ?

Comment: Also the program runs fine if I eliminate the where condition. But in the output the timestamp value is also there like 2017-05-01 10:11:28.0  is displayed in the for_date field. I think this might be the reason why the dates were not matching. Can u suggest something to overcome this.

Comment: the code ran when I changed my query to  sql="select reporting_date,for_date,outage_date,outage_time,stat_detail,res_date,rest_time,rest_reason from ISGS_table where for_date='2017-05-01 10:11:28.0'";

Comment: If you only want to match on the date part then the easiest (though not the most efficient) way would be `... WHERE DateValue(for_date)=?`.